# How to extract 'value' from both distance and duration in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, extract

I am working on a set of data. How do we extract 'value' from this DataFrame? Thanks.

This is the dataframe:

```
                           distance                          duration status
0  {'text': '0.5 km', 'value': 532}  {'text': '8 mins', 'value': 452}     OK
1  {'text': '0.7 km', 'value': 682}  {'text': '9 mins', 'value': 561}     OK
2  {'text': '0.6 km', 'value': 646}  {'text': '9 mins', 'value': 539}     OK
3  {'text': '0.3 km', 'value': 301}  {'text': '4 mins', 'value': 219}     OK
4  {'text': '0.3 km', 'value': 339}  {'text': '5 mins', 'value': 307}     OK
5  {'text': '0.4 km', 'value': 418}  {'text': '6 mins', 'value': 357}     OK
6  {'text': '0.5 km', 'value': 537}  {'text': '7 mins', 'value': 436}     OK
7  {'text': '0.4 km', 'value': 434}  {'text': '6 mins', 'value': 367}     OK
8  {'text': '0.4 km', 'value': 394}  {'text': '6 mins', 'value': 341}     OK
```

Comment: what is your expected output format?

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? If so, the question should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: @user3664111 - Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df[['distance_text','distance_value']]=df['distance'].str.replace("text|value|{|}|'|:",'').str.split(',',expand=True)
df[['duration_text','duration_value']]=df['duration'].str.replace("text|value|{|}|'|:",'').str.split(',',expand=True)
df=df[['distance_text','distance_value','duration_text','duration_value','status']]
```

Output:

```
  distance_text distance_value duration_text duration_value status
0        0.5 km            532        8 mins            452     OK
1        0.7 km            682        9 mins            561     OK
2        0.6 km            646        9 mins            539     OK
3        0.3 km            301        4 mins            219     OK
4        0.3 km            339        5 mins            307     OK
5        0.4 km            418        6 mins            357     OK
6        0.5 km            537        7 mins            436     OK
7        0.4 km            434        6 mins            367     OK
8        0.4 km            394        6 mins            341     OK
```